# Why do error message appear in R using websocket (Reuters)?

Tags: r, websocket, reuters

I an using the same code as in this example https://github.com/Refinitiv/websocket-api/blob/master/Applications/Examples/R/market_price.R
However, got the following error in this line, can anybody help to fix it?

```
> # Start websocket handshake
> ws_address = paste("ws://", hostname, ":", port, "/", sep="")
> cat(paste("Connecting to WebSocket", ws_address, "...\n"))
Connecting to WebSocket ws://127.0.0.1:15000/ ...
> con = websocket(ws_address, port=as.integer(port), subprotocol="tr_json2", version=13)
Error in websocket(ws_address, port = as.integer(port), subprotocol = "tr_json2",  : 
  Connection error
```

After I tried following code and run the same line and the error changed

```
> library(httpuv)

Attaching package: ‘httpuv’

The following object is masked from ‘package:websockets’:

    service

> library(websocket)

Attaching package: ‘websocket’

The following object is masked from ‘package:httpuv’:

    WebSocket

> s <- startServer("127.0.0.1", 15000,
+                  list(
+                    onWSOpen = function(ws) {
+                      # The ws object is a WebSocket object
+                      cat("Server connection opened.\n")
+                      
+                      ws$onMessage(function(binary, message) {
+                        cat("Server received message:", message, "\n")
+                        ws$send(message)
+                      })
+                      ws$onClose(function() {
+                        cat("Server connection closed.\n")
+                      })
+                    }
+                  )
+ )
> 
> ws <- websocket::WebSocket$new("ws://127.0.0.1:15000/")
> ws$onMessage(function(event) {
+   cat("Client received message:", event$data, "\n")
+ })
> 
> # Wait for a moment before running next line
> ws$send("hello world")
Error in wsSend(private$wsObj, msg) : invalid state
Server connection opened.
> con = websocket(ws_address, port=as.integer(port), subprotocol="tr_json2", version=13)
Error in websocket(ws_address, port = as.integer(port), subprotocol = "tr_json2",  : 
  Connection timeout
```

Alternatively, may be there different ways to get same result as `websocket(ws_address, port=as.integer(port), subprotocol="tr_json2", version=13)` command